# Deleting Windows 7 Fonts safely, Required for normal OS operation only English

Tags: windows-7, fonts, truetype-fonts

In windows 7 there are an array of fonts that are not used by the operating system, Fonts that are more nessisary for other languages, or for displaying languages in things like the browser, or some program made in those languages.

IF, I only need access to normal english text, even if I view non-english things

IF I am OK with non-english things "breaking" or showing wrong charachters.

IF i do not change permissions, or intend on deleting the fonts that do not delete normally.

IF it is only for the operating system itself, and not other added programs (like say having Office on)

CAN, I delete all fonts/font families that simply delete out of the system, without loosing functionality of the operating system.

What fonts should NOT be deleted , for standard English system operations, THAT will actually delete easily.

For extra Points :-)
I am going to add my own legit licenced font items , and the other fonts are in the way, and get in the way on all lists .  Will i see any problems with putting in Restricted character set TTS font items?

Comment: Fonts for alphabetic languages are tiny compared to ideographic ones, but the latter are not installed by default anyways. If you want space on your system drive, you should focus on the "Installer" folder.

Comment: I am back to "walking" as suggested, until i know more.
MANY things it is not so much the space, it is thier existance all over the system. Everytime i go to do something , i am presented with 10times what I wanted.  But still missing most important things for ME.

Comment: I believe in Windows 7 you have the option to "hide" fonts.

Comment: Yes i see that, but a "SuperUser" :-) doesnt hide operating system files from themselves , because then some virus comes along and uses hidden and system properties, and the user is no longer in control of thier system.   So the hidden fonts do not get out of my face (hide).

Comment: Then just go ahead and remove all the weird looking fonts (except [Marlett](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=134861) which is used by the system). All the common fonts like Arial, Times New Roman, Courier New, Consolas, etc. shoud stay there otherwise web pages will display terribly.

Comment: IS that your final answer :-)    ok sounds good, i was just wondering if anyone found out if some odd font was very nessisary, before I find out the hard way.

Comment: Also the default UI font in recent Windows versions is Segoe UI. Since it looks quite nice, you may consider keeping it.